# Laravel I added morphmany SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'staff.staff_id' in 'field list'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I store the data correctly but when I try to get a data in edit function it shows me this
error

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'staff.staff_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `users`.*, `staff`.`staff_id` as `pivot_staff_id`, `staff`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `staff`.`staff_type` as `pivot_staff_type`, `staff`.`role` as `pivot_role`, `staff`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at`, `staff`.`updated_at` as `pivot_updated_at` from `users` inner join `staff` on `users`.`id` = `staff`.`user_id` where `staff`.`staff_id` in (2) and `staff`.`staff_type` = App\Models\Investor)

```
//investor relationship
     public function staff()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(User::class, 'staff')
                    ->withPivot(['role'])
                    ->withTimestamps();
    }
//user relationship

    public function investors()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Investor::class, 'staff');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't follow [naming conventions](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions) so you should determine the **`foreign key`** and **`"other key"`** for the relationship:

```
 public function staff()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(User::class, 'staff','name of table',
                                                   'foreignPivotKey','relatedPivotKey);
}
```

I don't know your table columns name but in your case can be something like below:

```
public function staff()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(User::class, 'staff','staffabels',
                                                   'staffabel_id','staff_id')
                ->withPivot(['role'])
                ->withTimestamps();
}

public function investors()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Investor::class, 'staff','staffabels',
                                         'staff_id','staffable_id');
}
```